# No matching declaration found error in Solidity

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity

The code I have:

```
function approveRequest(uint256 index) public {
    Request storage request = requests[index];

    require(approvers[msg.sender]);
    require(!requests[index].approvals[msg.sender]);

    requests[index].approvals[msg.sender] = true;
    requests[index].approvalCount++;

    // ...
}
```

is giving the following error:

```
No matching declaration found after argument-dependent lookup.
```

at the *require*

[image]

Comment: Show approvers mapping.
how are you declaring mapping?

Comment: i have declared it like this:  ` address[] public approvers; ` @AbdulMaajid

Comment: You are using approvers as array so you have to use index to access address.

Answer (score 0):

You are using an `array` which means your approvers stored like `index` - `address`. With `address` type you can check if the specified index contains needed address. For example:

`require(approvers[0] == address(0xa846bc19E8ab8Bb0e0bf386853D8C5e199F0Af9b)`

To check if there is a needed address in the whole array, you need to write a loop which is very gas-expensive. To save gas and time, you can use an `mapping`. It assumes that all possible values are exist and always returns `false` or `0` if some value was not specified directly.
You can use is like this:

`mapping (address => bool) approvers`